# Need to control 2 DC motors powered using arduino mini and l298n from about range of 100m

Tags: motor, arduino-pro-mini, wireless

I need to control 2 DC motors which are arranged with arduino mini and L298N module from a distance of 100m wirelessly, what is the easiest and cheapest way of doing so?I checked RC controllers and xbee but they are way too expensive! 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE. Please be aware that this is not a free design house or an on-demand online technical encyclopedia. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cheapest way is probably using nRF24L01+, a 2.4 GHz transceiver. It should be possible to communicate over 100 m, using a slow speed and without any obstacles in between. If you need a better/faster communication, either use a version with an external antenna and/or use other frequences (using different transceivers, below 1 GHz). The last options are more expensive.